# Ubuntu 13.10 keeps freezing frequently

Tags: 13.10, freeze

I have a huge problem since I've updated to Ubuntu 13.10.
Previously this problem did not occur with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and later with 13.04 (though with 13.04 and 13.10 there's also a problem with ntfs partitions mounting).
My computer freezes very frequently. Every 2-3h of work I need to power-cycle it. It is very frustrating to be honest. I have no idea why is this happening.
I'm running a Sony Vaio VPC-F11M1E and have Windows 8.1 as my primary system.

My question is: how can I avoid it?

What files do you need to help me? Any log files required?
Beer for anyone who will help me.
Maybe should I return to 12.04 LTS?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Only for me, it's occurring every 15 minutes or so.  I may be wrong, but I think it has something to do with either the Alt key or the Super key having been pressed and the gui trying to bring up some panel.  Have you noticed a pattern to your freezings?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is no pattern. It happened for example when I was watching Starcraft II streams on Twitch TV. But not only then. No idea how to go around it.
I removed 13.10 and got myself 12.04 - this one's stable.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug which has been already reported on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1199877 Ubuntu 13.10 seems to have some memory leak. We hope this gets fixed asap.